# How to implement deletion by expression in a generic repository?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

Some details. Generic repository contains method GetByCondition:

```
    public IQueryable<T> GetByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) => 
        DbContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).AsNoTracking();
```

How implement Delete by expression? For example like below:

```
    public IQueryable<T> DeleteByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) =>
        DbContext.Set<T>().RemoveRange(expression);
```

Now it implement like:

```
public void Remove(T entity) => PintDbContext.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entity);
```

And called like below:

```
var item = await repo.Test.GetByCondition(test => test.Id.Equals(testId))
myRepo.Test.Remove(item);
```

Would like to call like below:

```
DeleteByCondition(test => test.Id.Equals(testId))
```

Edit: If i doing like below:

```
public void DeleteByCondition(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
     var entitiesToDelete = DbContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).ToList();
     DbContext.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entitiesToDelete);
}
```

then I get a compilation error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from
> 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T, object>>' to
> 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T, bool>>'

Comment: You could do `DbContext.Set<T>().RemoveRange(DbContext.Set<T>().Where(expression));` but that would load the entities into memory first. You may want to disable tracking for this query. Is this definitely EF6?

Comment: Remove this code to begin with. EF Core is already generic. A DbContext is already a generic multi-entity Repository and Unit-of-work. DbSet already is a single-entity Repository. EF Core 7 [added ExecuteDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates) for such bulk operations BUT ORMs in general are *not* the correct tool for batch/bulk operations. They're meant to work on graphs of objects, to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of database rows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You missed  `.ExecuteDelete()` from the end of that last code block

Comment: @DavidG facepalm

Comment: In EF Core 7, no matter what entities you use, you can use `context.Tests.Where(t => t.Category == "Integration").ExecuteDeleteAsync();` and get `DELETE Tests Where Category=@category` executed with a parameter value of `"Integration"`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks, but I have already given up implementing this in the generic repository and now work with DbSet. In the end, I will remove generic repository  from the project as unnecessary abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

You have to retrieve entities first and then delete them from `DbSet`:

```
public void DeleteByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{
    var entitiesToDelete = DbContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).ToList();
    DbContext.Set<T>().RemoveRange(entitiesToDelete);
}
```

UPDATE 1: If you don't want to retrieve items first there is tricky and unsafe way to do it. The idea is to manually construct a SQL query and execute it using the [`ExecuteSqlCommandAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommandasync) method. To do this we need table name and where condition. We can get the first one from `DbContext` and the second one by converting linq to sql using [`ToQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring) method.

```
public async Task DeleteByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    {
        var entityType = typeof(T);
        var tableName = DbContext.Model.FindEntityType(entityType).Relational().TableName;
        var query = DbContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).ToQueryString();
        var deleteQuery = $"DELETE FROM {tableName} WHERE {query.Substring(query.IndexOf("WHERE") + 6)}";
        await DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(deleteQuery);
    }
```

Be aware that this is an unsafe drafting solution that does not take into account different schemes and other features.

UPDATE 2: There is a great new feature in EF core 7: [ExecuteUpdate and ExecuteDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates).

Calling `ExecuteDelete` or `ExecuteDeleteAsync` on a `DbSet` immediately deletes all entities of that `DbSet` from the database. For example, to delete all Tag entities:

```
await context.Tags.ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```

More interestingly, the query can contain a filter. For example:

```
await context.Tags.Where(t => t.Text.Contains(".NET")).ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```

This executes the following SQL:

```
DELETE FROM [t]
FROM [Tags] AS [t]
WHERE [t].[Text] LIKE N'%.NET%'
```

So if you use EF core 7 you can do solve your problem with a single line of code:

```
public async Task DeleteByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
    => await DbContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).ExecuteDeleteAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's is like what I'm doing now. I edited my post, pleace check it out.  I thought it could be implement without `select`

Comment: @user6408649 the short answer is no. The slightly longer answer is yes. I've updated my answer with an example of a clever workaround to the entity extraction restriction, but it may require more debugging and tweaking.

Comment: The answer is yes, with the correct tool. EF Core 7 offers bulk deletes but in general ORMs are not good at bulk operations. No "generic" repository is needed when a higher-level generic abstraction like an ORM is used. After all, `DbSet<T>` is generic. `IQueryable<T>` is generic

Comment: While EF Core 7 allows  `context.Tests.Where(t => t.Category == "Integration").ExecuteDeleteAsync();` the ORM is acting as just a query builder, of which there are several.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh great addition, thank you. It's very young feature and i really forgot abot it!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated my answer with your advice. Thanks again for the comment.